# How can I get(know) the menuid of a specific menu in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to add a submenu to Package-Explorer's project context menu. But, I can't find the menuid of that menu.

So my question is how to find a menuid in eclipse?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything. I can't guess out any thing. I even don't know where(which plugin) this package-explorer comes from.

Comment: Let me look. A [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=eclipse+plugin+development+menu) take me to [this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#contribute_packageexplorer)

Comment: Thank you. I got "open Plug-in Artifact".

Comment: TempleWing: The answer you have accepted does not work for myself and others. As stated by @Bananeweizen, the Plug-in Menu Spy does not seem to give a valid `locationURI` for context menus. Are you sure that it works for you? Have you verified the effectiveness of it?

Comment: @TempleWing: Do you mean `locationURI` when you say, "menuid?"

Comment: @StockB quiet an old topic but this topic is the first google resut for this query. Indeed, in my case, the given path isnt valid, however it also links to the contributing plugin manifest and there I was able to retrieve the locationURI I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Plugin Spy gives you easily information about the running UI.

Press "Alt+Shift+F1" to get information about the current running Eclipse plugin / data types / screen.

Press "Alt + Shift + F2"  and select a menu to see who is contributing this menu.

for more information:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy

For Eg: Plugin Spy for PackageExplorer itself will show like this : 
 [image: PackageExplorer SPY] 
 
and for popup menu in the packaghe explorer for e.g. for refresh it shows like this : 
 [image: Refresh SPY]

Comment: Plugin-Spy does not work for context menus. And the SWT spy (which you linked to) is something different than Plugin Spy.

Comment: Why not, click first "Alt + Shift + F2" and then right click to open the context menu and click teh menu.

Comment: Because I tested it. And on my Ubuntu system it does not work.

Comment: It doesn't open the Plugin spy window at all? or not working means what?

Comment: You got negative'd because the `menu:locationURI` given in the Plug-in Menu Spy does **not** actually add the `menuContribution` to the specified location. You apparently did not try to implement your solution to verify it works. Despite appearing to give a locationURI, it is not valid when it comes to context menus, as stated by Banadeweizen. Poor @TempleWing has accepted the answer, also without verifying it works, further adding to confusion of future visitors (such as myself). I do not have the rep req'd to negative this answer, but I would if I could.

Comment: In fact, the screenshots you have chosen for your example do not show any `locationURI` at all, which further adds to the confusion. Although certain elements in a context menu *do* display a `locationURI` it is never a valid `locationURI` for a user-defined plugin menu (in my experience). If you could provide in your answer an example of a valid `locationURI` for a context menu, found with Plug-in Menu Spy, I would be happy to +1 your answer. As it stands, I cannot +1 you, nor can I +1 @TempleWing's question when the accepted answer does not appear to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class which contains constant values : **org.eclipse.ui.menus.MenuUtil**

For example, you should see this Eclipse help link ( Mars version ) :
[Eclipse constant class MenuUtil](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Fconstant-values.html)